# How to add admin "user id" in "catalog_product_entity" table in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database

I want to check which user adding product and listing user wise products in **Manage products** section.

Answer (score 0):

create a product attribute like `admin_id` and assign to attribute set from admin and while creating product on before save event of product try to save logged in admin id in that created product attribute

You need to create a observer.

`app/code/local/YourPackageName/YourModuleName/etc/config.xml` - the configuration file

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_before><!-- observe the event -->
            <observers>
                <save_admin_id>
                    <class>YourPackageName_YourModuleName_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>autoAdminId</method>
                </save_admin_id>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

`app/code/local/YourPackageName/YourModuleName/Model/Observer.php` - the observe class

```
<?php 
class YourPackageName_YourModuleName_Model_Observer {
    public function autoAdminId($observer) {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session'); 
        $userId = $user->getUser()->getUserId();        
        $product->setAdminId($userId);
    } 
}
```

Comment: ok.How to view id wise produts?Such as I have 1500 products in database. My id is 1 and I create 10 products now i want to only show 10 products when i means admin id 1 is login.

Comment: $userArray = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getData();
       $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
       echo  $userId = $user->getUser()->getUserId(); 
Using this code i receive admin/user id who login.Now how to set this id in these attribute set?